# Remove special characters in a pandas column using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a pandas dataframe where a column has non numeric values in it.Is there a way that i can replace characters only while retaining the numbers in the column.I am very new to applying regex patterns to clean data and highly appreciate  if someone could point me towards the right regex pattern .

The final output has to be a single digit float of the type [0-9].[0-9] but there will be values which dont follow those standards too and i would need to find those numbers and then scale them .

Eg:

```
Col A

'7.8.',
'5..3',
'%3.2',
'   ',
'3.*8',
'3.8*',
'140',
'14.5 of HGB',
'>14.5',
'<14.5',
'14,5'
'14. 5'
```

Expected Output :

```
Col A

'7.8',
'5.3',
'3.2',
'0',
'3.8',
'3.8',
'140',
'14.5',
'14.5',
'14.5',
'14.5',
'14.5'
```

P.S. the objective is to extract only the numbers and then convert it into a float so that i can do some calculations on it.

Thanks,

Abdul

Comment: What is your expected output? Should `3.*8` be `3.8` and `5..3` be `5.3`??

Comment: What about `1.2.3`? Does it become `123`, `12.3`, `1.23`...?

Comment: A suggested first step: replace everything that is not a digit or period, then go from there.  `unallowed = re.compile(r'[^\d\.]')`, then `s.str.replace(unallowed, '')`

Comment: @RafaelC if that s the case then i would just need the first occuring dot and use it as the value. 1.2.3 then translates to 1.2 ignoring .3

Comment: @ALollz Yes the expected output has to be of the format [0-9].[0-9] with all the special characters removed.3.*8 has to be 3.8 and 5..3 has to be 5.3.If it has a value like 140 then i would just need to keep it as it is and convert it into  a float so that i can scale it later .

Comment: @brad solomon i tried it and  it does not seem to solve cases like 5.5.  .Any suggestions on how to handle that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex groups the digits on either side of the '.' ignoring all non-digits. The code uses these groups to create the required output. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bo97D9/1)

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_input(m):
    print(m.group(0))
    if m:
        val = m.group(1)
        if m.group(2):
            val = val + '.' +m.group(2)
    return val

a = pd.DataFrame({'colA':
   ['7.8.',
    '5..3',
    '%3.2',
    '   ',
    '3.*8',
    '3.8*',
    '140',
    '5.5.',
    '14.5 of HGB',
    '>14.5',
    '<14.5',
    '14,5',
   '14. 5']})
a['colA'].str.replace('[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(?:\.)?[^\d]*(\d)*[^\d]*', clean_input)
```

Output:

```
0      7.8
1      5.3
2      3.2
3         
4      3.8
5      3.8
6      140
7      5.5
8     14.5
9     14.5
10    14.5
11    14.5
12    14.5
```

Regex explanation:

- `\d` - matches a digit
- `[^<pattern>]` - matches any character except the
- `[^\d]` - matches any character except for digits.
- `[^\d]+`- matches one or more of the above.
- `(?:)` - is non-capturing group where the matched characters are not captured.
- `<pattern>?`  - zero or one occurance of the pattern.
- `\.` - since `.` is a meta character, it has to be escaped with `\`

Comment: Can you comment the values for which this didn't work? Maybe, you can add it to the question.

Comment: this almost solved my problem .i have a few values still which have few text in them and certain symbols .I did not know how to come up with unique values which are other than of the format [0-9].[0-9] and the examples i have listed there is based on the regexes i have tried and ran into errors with.i have few more problems coming up. how do i extract data from 14.5 of HGB,>14.5,<14.5, 14,5

Comment: Thank you for the update. I ran the code with the additional inputs and it seems to work. Can you check again once?

Comment: thanks so much for the solution .this indeed worked like a charm.could you please explain this regex at a detailed level so that i can apply it in the future .?

Answer (score 2):

Another take: split a string by periods, extract all digits from the first and second fragments, concatenate them with a period.

```
parts = df['colA'].str.split('\.')
part0 = parts.str[0].str.extract('(\d+)').fillna('0')
part1 = parts.str[1].str.extract('(\d+)').fillna('0')
part0 + "." + part1
```

Output:

```
#0    7.8
#1    5.0
#2    3.2
#3    0.0
#4    3.8
#5    3.8
#6  140.0
```